# Renormalization for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Can someone explain to me the processes of renormalization and regularization used in quantum field theory and similar fields in a way that a pure mathematician might make sense of it? Is there a mathematically rigorous way to go about doing them? Could you give an example of a basic renormalization and explain why it was necessary?

Comment: See answers [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/62770).

Comment: That page seems a little advanced. My background is mathematical logic, so this is all very foreign to me.

Comment: In my humble opinion, renormalization is simply removing some specific "wrongness" introduced in QFT equations due to unjustified self-action anzats. Warning: my opinion is not widely accepted.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should start reading a bit about the history of QFT as it would give the justification for the mathematics behind renormalization. A good starting point could be:

I - https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-field-theory/qft-history.html

You won't, however, be completely free from physics while trying to grasp the concepts. I found a paper that claims to explain QFT and RG (renormalization group) in just 11 pages.

II - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4897.pdf

Not sure if it is enough, but you might give it a try. 
There is also the text from Weinberg about QFT development:

III - http://www.fafnir.phyast.pitt.edu/py3765/WeinbergQFThistory.pdf

That may help on organizing the subjects in your head.

Comment: 6 years later, but the answer is still appreciated!